# How to build a Jenkins project only when two other projects have successfully been built?

Tags: jenkins

I've figured out how to trigger another Jenkins project build after a successful build, but how do you solve next situation:

Project A triggers project B and C. Project D should only be build if project B and C have successfully been built. I can't configure B to trigger project D because I'm not sure project C has been built yet, and vice versa.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The "build after other projects are built" suggested by Akhil will not accomplish the stated goal. It will trigger Project D after *either* Project B or Project C is built. Use the [Join Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin).

Answer (score 3):

There is an option in "Build Triggers" option to "Build after other projects are built". Here is the snapshot for the same:

[image]

In the Projects to watch, mention: `Project B, Project C`(Note that multiple projects are mentioned with a comma separated value)

Comment: This will trigger after *either* B or C is built. OP wanted after *both*.

Comment: Multiple projects can be specified like 'abc, def' per the Jenkins UI tooltip.

Comment: @EricP is right, It will trigger when either B or C is built.

Comment: I have a slightly different situation. Lets say there are two projects A and B only. I want to trigger B when A completes successfully. Here I also want to pass an input parameter to project B which i need to derive from the outcome of project A. Is there are way to do this..?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can orchestrate this with a Pipeline job. For example you could have another job doing this (or you could make job A into a pipeline job and skip the first `build` step)

```
build 'A'

parallel(firstTask: {
    build 'B'
}, secondTask: {
    build 'C'
})

build 'D'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use view name with job name example:-

if your one job in stg and other in a so post-build would be:-

> success {
> build job: "QA/job"
> }